# How to fix ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc syntax errors

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, bashrc, .profile, syntax

Ubuntu 18.04.4 (automatic upgrade from 18.04.3 just a few weeks ago)
/bin/bash

After I log in from the Gnome shell, this message appears while the screen is just plain purple and before the desktop appears:

```
Error found when loading /home/hfinger/.profile:  

/home/hfinger/.profile: line 1: #: command not found  
/home/hfinger/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '('
/home/hfinger/.bashrc: line 1: '# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.'  

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.  
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Trouble is, what is the problem? I have searched AskUbuntu but no-one appears to have experienced this exact problem. I don't think it is the upgrade because it had been running for about a month before this problem appeared.

I have never touched these two files because I am quite happy to let the system create and configure them. Also, I try to keep Ubuntu as vanilla as possible to avoid having to restore settings after upgrading to a new release. For what it is worth, here are the first lines of each of these files:

```
.profile, line 1: # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.  
.bashrc, line 1: # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
```

How do I need to fix these files? What additional information should I provide so that someone more knowledgeable than I can solve this dopey problem?

Comment: I wonder if the files have something like an extraneous byte order mark (BOM) at the start? What is the output of `file ~/.bashrc` for example? or `xxd -l16 ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Could the user shell be incorrectly set? It should be /bin/bash. Maybe a variation of `sudo usermod -s` might fix it?

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if your files have a non-printing byte sequence at the start - for example a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - perhaps as a result of having edited them in a word processor program or Windows text editor.

For example, given

```
$ file profile bashrc
profile: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
bashrc:  UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

(where `profile` and `bashrc` are local copies of my `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` with byte sequence `0xFE 0xFF` inserted at the start) then

```
$ bash -c 'source profile; source bashrc'
profile: line 1: #: command not found
bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bashrc: line 1: `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.'
```

The simplest fix is to use `dos2unix`, which removes the BOM by default:

```
$ dos2unix profile bashrc
dos2unix: converting file profile to Unix format...
dos2unix: converting file bashrc to Unix format...

$ file profile bashrc
profile: ASCII text
bashrc:  UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Or you can simply replace the files with fresh copies from the `/etc/skel` directory as you discovered (although obviously you will lose any customizations that way).

---

Other ways to check for non-printing bytes are

```
cat -A ~/.profile ~/.bashrc
```

in which a BOM will show up as a control sequence like `M-oM-;M-?#` or using `xxd` or `od` to examine the byte sequences directly

```
head -1 ~/.profile | od -tx1

xxd -l16 ~/.profile
```

The `diff` command is helpful insofar as confirming there *is* a difference, but not in identifying what the difference is:

```
$ diff profile ~/.profile
1c1
< # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
---
> # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
```

Comment: +1 Good info. Funny that OP says they never touched the files.

Comment: @heynnema thanks - it's still only a guess though, we will need the OP to confirm by checking the first few bytes of their `.bak` files

Comment: A leading BOM was the problem. Kate was set to add a BOM to any UTF-8 file it opened or edited. Disabled it and all is well. Thank god I didn't have customised .profile or .bashrc files.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to check the user's shell...

If you don't have `Users and Groups` application already installed, install it this way...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`

Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type "Users", select `Users and Groups` application, click on the account name, then Advanced Settings, Advanced tab, and verify the correct Shell of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: This presupposes that there is a shell in which `#` is something other than a comment character...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04.4 (automatic upgrade from 18.04.3 just a few weeks ago)
/bin/bash

I don't know what the problem was but this is the way I fixed it:

```
$ cd ~ 
$ which bash
/bin/bash  
$ mv .profile .profile.bak  
$ mv .bashrc .bashrc.bak  
$ cd /etc/skel/  
$ cp .profile ~/.profile  
$ cp .bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

(Note: `/bin/bash` is the correct location for `bash`.)

Thanks everybody for your comments and assistance.

Comment: Can you do `diff ~/.profile ~/.profile.bak` so that we can see the difference between the two files and guess what the problem was?