# .profile suddenly doesn't like comments

Tags: xubuntu, gtk3, qt5, .profile

I'm running Xubuntu 20.10 on a MBA 2012. I wanted to use my GTK theme on a QT program, so I did a little searching and ended up with adding `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` to my `~/.profile`. That works, but whenever I log in, I get an error saying that the command `#` on line one can't be found. I assume this is a comment. I thought my line endings could be incorrect, so I opened VIM and changed them to UNIX, which didn't do anything. Coincidentally, Plank won't launch. Is there a better alternative to what I added to my `~/.profile`, or is the error completely separate? Attached is the full `~/.profile`.

```sh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

# include Mycroft commands
source ~/.profile_mycroft
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
```

Comment: You mention both `~/.profile` and `~/profile`. Is it just a typo here, or you might indeed have redundant files like this?

Comment: Also you could add syntax highlighting to the code block by adding `sh` after the first (opening) \```. LIke this: \```sh

Comment: Also, would it not ruin something if, on the last two lines, you tried putting the `export` statement before the `source` statement? Because if one doesn't depend on the other, then I would try out whether leaving `source` for last changes things or not...

Comment: First comment was a typo. Didn't realise about the second one, thanks! Third one, the two are completely separate, shoulda added a line break or something to make it clearer. I'll try it!

Comment: Moving the last line seems to have fixed Plank, but I still get the error when I log in.

Comment: Okay, it seems using the tilde `~` as home alias does not work in `.profile`. So expand tilde `~` to literally what it means: `/home/BoeingLikesToDab/.profile_mycroft`.

Comment: What does `.profile_mycroft` contain?

Comment: Perhaps there is a byte order mark or other non-printing character before the #. See for example [How to fix ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc syntax errors](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215014/178692)

Comment: Steeldriver's answer worked! I'll mark this as a duplicate if I can.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try swapping the order of the `export` and `source` statements, so that `source` comes later.
2. According to [@muru's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340492/profile-suddenly-doesnt-like-comments#comment2289466_1340497), try using `.` instead of `source`, which is more bulletproof when encountered by various interpreters.
3. It seems [in some cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225685/unable-to-add-folder-to-path-in-profile-file#comment383595_225685) using the tilde `~` as home alias does not work in `~/.profile`. (Even though your use case might work, as suggested by @muru, again.) Anyways, it's worth remembering that the `$HOME` env var tends to be more bulletproof.

Your last lines then could look like this:

```sh
# "I wanted to use my GTK theme on a QT program [...]"
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2

# include Mycroft commands
. "$HOME/.profile_mycroft"
```

Comment: `~` works just fine in the conditions in which it is expanded. `~` is not expanded in the middle of a word, like `export PATH=...:~/...`, which is probably what that comment is referring to. Using it in `source ~/...` will work fine, but `source` is *not* standard (`.` is, `source` is a bash builtin equivalent to `.`), and `~/.profile` could be sourced by shells other than bash.

Comment: Doesn't work, same error as before. I don't think there is an issue with the Mycroft line, it's been there for a few months without any problems.

Comment: @BoeingLikesToDab Then remove the `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` for a little while, or just comment it out, and see if it makes the `command not found` thing go away at this point or not...